# Facebook Graph API: I want to fetch a feed of user who have not given permission "read_stream" from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, feed

I want to fetch a feed of user whose permission "read_stream" have been not given for my app from Facebook Graph API using "/{user id}/feed".

Although I found the specification in case that the app have permission "read_stream" of the user, I cound not find one in case that the app have no permission.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

When I accessed to API command, the API returned incomplete data contains the user's public post, etc.

So, does anyone know the behavior of this API command in case that app have no permission?

Comment: Have you tried it via the (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) graph API Explorer?

Comment: Yes. I've tried. But I'd like to know correct specification.

Comment: Can you tell us what were the results of your test?